# Angularjs getting the indexOf an array always returning -1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble removing an item inside an array using splice. I can't seem to make it work, it always returns a `-1` value.

**json object**

```
{
"_id": "5a61ad6fd5df1761dd2eb1f1",
"branch": "Lucban",
"__v": 0,
"building": [
    {
        "name": "mhq",
        "floors": [
            "ground floor",
            "2nd floor"
        ]
    }
],
"dateCreated": "2018-01-19T08:33:51.761Z"}
```

**html**

```
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary text-capitalize" ng-repeat="floor in vm.selectedItem.building[0].floors">{{floor}}
<i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="vm.removeItem($index)"></i></span>
```

**controller**

```
vm.removeItem = removeItem;
function removeItem(data) { // data is $index of the object
  var index = vm.selectedItem.building[0].floors.indexOf(data); //always throwing -1
  console.log(index);
  vm.selectedItem.building[0].floors.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already passing an index of an item, you don't need to find search for index again

```
function removeItem(index) {
   if(vm.selectedItem.building[0].floors[index]){
     vm.selectedItem.building[0].floors.splice(index, 1);
   } else {
     console.log("No such element present at index "+index)
   }
}
```

If you been applied any sorting or filtering on `floors` object, then passing index to `removeItem` function would not expected. In such case I'd recommend you to pass unique `floor` id, so that you can determine what item from collection based on that `uniqueid`.

Comment: I think passing data should be safer, in case orderBy filter is used in `ng-repeat`

Comment: Good point! but even that wouldn't help much, expect the fact that there is `uniqueId` present on that record. Check updated answer, Thanks for heads up ;)